# Reading YAML with Jackson ignores keys without values

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I have the following YAML file:

```
---
-
id: 001
start: 21.11.2018
additional:
dependency:
result: 2
```

which I like to read in with jackson as a simple `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

For this I use the following code

```
 private List<Map<String, Object>> readDefaultInputAsMap() {
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputResource, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this returns a map with only `id`, `start` and `result`, so the two others are ignored.

How can I get Jackson to parse the file and create the full map and with e.g. `null` as values for the empy keys ? (Or any other default value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it does that by default. Double-check the format of your YML (because your example seems to be invalid). Here is what worked for me:

*test.yml*:

```
---
- id: 001
  start: 21.11.2018
  additional:
  dependency:
  result: 2
```

*Test.java*:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
        try {
            final Object value = objectMapper.readValue(App.class.getResource("test.yml"), new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
            });

            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I got the result:

```
[{id=1, start=21.11.2018, additional=null, dependency=null, result=2}]
```

As you see, `additional` and `dependency` are both `null`.

Comment: acutally, the format of the yaml file seems not to be a problem. But I have found my error, which is false check at another part of the code, so you are absolutely right about the default behavior

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own Object (new class) with all possible attributes you want, for instance:

```
 class MyCompleteInfo {
    String id;
    String start;
    String additional;
    String dependency;
    String result;
 }
```

And use a List of it (as method return, and in your reader):

```
List<MyCompleteInfo >
```

Edit: You may have used @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) somewhere? 
You must not.

See [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields).

Comment: i do not know beforehand the attributes to build a class

Comment: You may have used @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) somewhere? You shouldn't.